# What is the term for using a Neural Network to create new data based on training data?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a large set of Training data which consists of various texts. They should be the input for my neural network. I have no output, or I don't know what to put as output.

Anyway, after the learning phase I want the neural network to create new texts based on the training data.
I read about this like „I made a bot watch 1000 hours of xy and asked it to write a new xy“.

Now my question is, what kind of machine learning is this? I am not looking for instructions on how to write it, but just a hint on how to find some keywords or tutorials. My Google searches so far were useless.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can usually be solved by an Encoder-Decoder architecture. This architecture would learn a set of latent vectors from your input, then try to output in whatever form you want. This architecture can be built with RNN, LSTM or CNN. Nowadays, attention-based models like transformers are more common among the big names. If you want to do text generation, you can start by reading about Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs).